# Center backgroundView X and Y Position of a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've a tableview and the image works fine for 4s and 5 devices but when tested on 6 and 6 plus it makes the image look like this...

The code I'm using is the following:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage        imageNamed:@"noSearchResults.png"]];
```

also used this but nothing got better.

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:
                                          [[UIImage imageNamed:@"noSearchResults.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:1.0
                                                                                                        topCapHeight:1.0]];
```

[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZDm0.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Which image is the background view?

Comment: The image that says no results found.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/YZDm0.png

Comment: Why do you need to use a stretchable image?

Comment: I dont need it to strech. this happens when I run the app on iphone 6 simulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your question it seems that you have set image in background of table.
If you had done same then it will set the image according to table view height and width. 
It might also be possible if you've not used image on proper resolution.

Can you please tell me the size of image you've used.

Please check are all four of the below images are used and stored in image xcassets.
1.) In 1x place image with resolution 320 x 480. 
 
2.) In 2x place image with resolution 640 x 960. 
3.) In Retina 4 2x place image with resolution 640 x 1136.
 
4.) in 3x place image with resolution 1242 x 2207.

Images of Retina 4 2x will upscale to resolution 750 x 1334. 
Images 3x will downscale to resolution 1080 x 1920.

Comment: I've noSearchResults-568h@2x.png (640 × 1136) , noSearchResults@2x.png (640 × 960)

Comment: Now you only need to add the image of size 1242 X 2207 that is @3x for 6+ and your problem will be solved.

Comment: but do I need to add the name to the image??? or any name and simply create a xcasset image set? because its not fuly working

Comment: I created 4 images named nohistory.png, nohistory@2x.png, nohistory-568h@2x.png, nohistory@3x.png and still got the same issue :(

Comment: Hi sorry for replying so late.
What you need to do is use Images.xcassets. please visit link below it will help you how to use xcassets and set image in table view without stretching in background.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_36Y6rDcKP0&feature=youtu.be

Then all you need to write this following code. I’ve used the same name given in Images.xcassets to new Image set ‘all_bg’.

[self.tblView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"app_bg"]]];